# Can a swf file be accessible to an included html page?

Tags: html, include, flash

Now i have two html pages.the Main page is Index.html which embeds a SWF file.Now i have included another Photoshoot.html in index.html.So can i access the methods of the embedded SWF file in button click event of Photoshoot.html.

Comment: what do you mean by "included another Photoshoot.html" ? in `iframe` ?

Comment: it means i m including photoshoot.html in index.html by include();

Comment: what is `include()` ? php method?